# OVH Api specific task sequence

Tags: api, dns, ovh

Is it possible somehow to know the sequence to perform a specific task?

For instance, domain registration.

API commands documented here: https://api.ovh.com/console/ but in order to do a specific task you need to know the sequence (create cart, availability check, create plan, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are no documentations about sequence at the moment. You have to find out by yourself. For example you need to checkout, try to execute that command and see what do you need in order to complete. Then you execute that command which should give you results and then see whats missing for that command. And by doing this, you can find the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there is no documentation about this API calls sequences to perform a given action.

But as OVH API is used by OVH Manager (the GUI where you can order & configure products), one way of knowing the sequence can be to make an order once via the OVH Manager, and thanks to the developer console of your browser, see which calls are made and then see the sequence.

This is definitively a boring solution, but that's the only one I know.

Comment: OVH manager does not give you any knowledge at all. 

Domain buying procedure OVH API
1. create cart
2. assign cart
3. put to cart
4. checkout

Domain buying procedure OVH manager
1. check domain availability
2. put to cart
3. select additional services
4. rules
5. checkout

Comment: As I said in the answer: OVH Manager dont, but the BROWSER CONSOLE used while browsing/ordering through the OVH Manager does. You'll be able to see all the API call made, and in which order.
Please read the answer before commenting.